# Multiple image upload from webservice in php json form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am creating a web service using php and json to upload multiple images
to move in the folder and in database, I am able to upload one image using this code

```
        $image_binary=base64_decode($real_img);
        $image_file = fopen("images/real/".time().$real_img.$id.'.jpg', 'wb');
        fwrite($image_file, $image_binary); 
        $image_path = "".$id.'.jpg';
        move_uploaded_file(fwrite($image_file, $image_binary), $image_path);
```

How can I use this code for multiple images if I get the multiple images in array.

Comment: What is "id" ? What is `$real_image` ? Explain more.

Comment: $real_image is the variable for the image I get.

Answer (score 0):

Loop it:
(untested)

```php
$images = array(0 => 'img1....jpg', 
                1 => 'img2....jpg');

uploadImages($images);

function uploadImages($images) {
    for($i = 0; count($images) > $i; $i++) {
        $image = $images[$i];

        $image_binary=base64_decode($image);
        $image_file = fopen("images/real/".time().$image.$id.'.jpg', 'wb');
        fwrite($image_file, $image_binary); 
        $image_path = "".$id.'.jpg';
        move_uploaded_file(fwrite($image_file, $image_binary), $image_path);
    }
}
```